# how to split an single array in to arrays - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need to split single array in to multiple arrays.

For example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pageviews] => 26
            [visits] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pageviews] => 9
            [visits] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pageviews] => 18
            [visits] => 9
        )
)
```

**I need to split the array like below:**

```
Array
(

            [ga:pageviews] => 26
            [ga:visits] => 20
)

Array
(
            [ga:pageviews] => 9
            [ga:visits] => 4
)

Array
(
            [ga:pageviews] => 18
            [ga:visits] => 9
)
```

How can i do this?

Any help will be thankful and grateful...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why do you need to split them, the values are already nicely listed up next to each other. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so using foreach:

```
foreach ( $original as $item ) {
    var_dump( array(
        'ga:pageviews' => $item['pageviews'],
        'ga:visits' => $item['visits'],
    ) );
}
```

Comment: not satisfying my need actually. It prints the same again... when i echo $splitted it returns me the same thing...

Comment: while i print $splitted it is printing the same input.. it doesnt print the multiple arrays... anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$array =     Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pageviews] => 26
            [visits] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pageviews] => 9
            [visits] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pageviews] => 18
            [visits] => 9
        )
)

for($x=0; $x<count($array); $x++){
   $newArray = $array[$x];       // that extract the second array, containing pageview and visits.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your samples, you seem to want to split one variable into multiple variables (or perhaps you used incorrect notation in the 2nd one?).  If that is the case, and you know how many arrays are in the starting variable, you can do this:

```
list($one, $two, $three) = $originalArray;
```

If you don't know how many arrays are in the original array, or there is more than a handful, I have to wonder why you would want to or need to do this in the first place...